# How to set read permissions on a Databricks Unity catalog for a personal access token?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm connecting excel on Databricks to read a specific unity catalog, however, the odbc simba connection that uses the token allows access to all unity data catalogs.

How can I restrict this access to a single catalog unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity Catalog sets permissions to the roles, not to the individual tokens. PATs are associated with the specific users, so if the user has access to the catalogs, then ODBC/JDBC driver will have access to them. But you need to check if you really have access to the data or you just have `USE_CATALOG`, ... permissions as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-privileges/privileges).

Comment: thank's Alex,
I was trying to generate the token with my user so I had more privileges. Thank you for your help